# I have tried several things but cannot get react-modal working correctly

Tags: reactjs, typescript, sass, react-modal

I'm looking for a simple Modal component in my React project.  I opted to go with https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-modal because it seemed popular.

But everything I've tried so far has the modal hugging the top-left of the parent DIV.  Here's the basic code I've tried:

```
<main className={styles.main}>
  <Modal
      isOpen={isShowModal}
      className={styles.modal}
      overlayClassName={styles.overlay}
      ariaHideApp={false}
      contentLabel='abc def'
    >
      Here is some modal content!<br/>
      Here is some modal content!<br/>
      Here is some modal content!<br/>
      Here is some modal content!<br/>
      Here is some modal content!<br/>
  </Modal>
</main>

.main {
  height: $page-height;  
  background: $sea-lord-background;
  padding: 20px 20px;
}

.modal {
  // margin-top: 500px;
  position: absolute;
  // // height: 300px;
  // // width: 500px;
  top: '50%';
  left: '50%';
  right: 'auto';
  bottom: 'auto';
  margin-right: '-50%';
  transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)';
  background-color: $gray;
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: lime;
}
```

But everything I've tried, I can't get the basic modal centered vertically & horizontally.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Ughhh, the problem was a translation error between CSS and SCSS.  The latter needs definitions like `top: 50%` and not `top: '50%'`;

I now have thing correctly centered.  I just need to fix the background color/opacity issues.

Comment: Btw another thing I learned from this exercise is that if you wish the Overlay opacity to not seep through to the modal then you need to use the RGBA approach, like this: `background-color: rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.75);`. If you don't do this then the opacity of the modal will be identical to the opacity of the overlay, which is likely not what you want.